# Cross checking two excel files in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am still fairly new to R and I am trying to write a function that takes two excel files as input. Then I am trying to say if the cell in each row in a given column does not match the cell in the corresponding row of the other excel file in a given column to delete the row from the first excel file.

I first tried

```
List <-function(group1,group){
  for (i in group1$Name){
    for (j in group$Name) {
      if (i != j){
        remove(i)}
}
```

If the data frames looked as follows

| Name | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

| Name | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 89 | Cell 4 |

The output would be

| Name | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |

Update: I have used intersect thanks to an answer on this question and am wondering is there a way to use intersect to check only one column? Meaning as long as the name matches keep the row even if the cells in other columns do not match? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
dplyr::intersect(df1, df2)

#      Name Column B
# 1: Cell 1   Cell 2
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use intersect to check only one column? Meaning as long as the name matches keep the row even if the cells in other columns do not match?